# maximum rows per value vs typical rows per value [teradata]

Tags: database, performance, indexing, rdbms, teradata

I've been reading about data demographics of teradata and came across with this two terms. It is mentioned that this two goes hand in hand to make good index choice, but I can't seem to understand exactly what is the difference between the two values.
Can anyone explain to me the exact difference between the two. Examples on how the values are derived would be really helpful.
I'm thinking both values will come from this query:

```
 sel <columnname>, count(*) 
 from <tablename>
```

Here are the definition of the two terms, btw.

```
    Maximum Rows/Value –No. of rows for the most-often-occurring value in the column.
    Typical Rows/Value –No. of rows for a typical value in the column.
```

Any inputs will be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my understanding of Maximum Rows/Value vs Typical Rows/Value.

Suppose (SQL Fiddle Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/27641/13/0)

```
SELECT MAX (COUNT ("sometext")) max_row_per_value
  FROM table1
GROUP BY id
```

And here is the result

```
MAX_ROW_PER_VALUE
7
```

In this case, when you look at id=1, there are 7 records for that value, being the maximum rows/value.

The typical rows/value is what I consider the AVG(), like this:

```
SELECT AVG (COUNT ("sometext")) typical_row_per_value
  FROM table1
GROUP BY id
```

Result

```
TYPICAL_ROW_PER_VALUE
4.5
```

Comment: It's a bit more complicated, the typical value is not always the same as average or median, but in most cases it's treated like that. Detailscan be found in Teradata's Database Design manual, Chapter 6: The Activity Transaction Modeling Process
Maximum and Typical Column Value Frequencies